# How to access model class values in another controller using singleton in swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, singleton

I have created a class with some variables and have not initialized with any default value, all variables should be assigned when web service call occurs. So I have initialized the instance of the class and assigned the value to the variables.

Here I want to access these values to all class file throughout the project. Is it possible? I do not want to use any saving methods like core data and user defaults also codable local storage.

Please help me out with this? We tried to access the model class value in another view controller. But we get a nil value. Thanks in Advance.

```
//MARK: Shared Instance
static let sharedInstance = Singleton()

//MARK: Local Variable    
var emptyStringArray : [String]? = nil
var completed : Bool!
var id : Int?
var title : String?
var userId : Int?

//MARK: Init Array
private init() { 
}

init(Fromarray  dictionary : [String:Any]) {
    completed = dictionary["completed"] as? Bool
    id = dictionary["id"] as? Int
    title = dictionary["title"] as? String
    userId = dictionary["userId"] as? Int
}
```

finally called in

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController { 

override func viewDidLoad() { 
  super.viewDidLoad() 
  let BoolValue = Singleton.sharedInstance.completed 
  print(BoolValue) 
}
```

Comment: Show your code. Where do you get `nil`?

Comment: class ViewController2: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let BoolValue = Singleton.sharedInstance.completed
        print(BoolValue)
     

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

Comment: Edit all your code onto the question. leave nothing in the comments to suffer!

Comment: `var emptyStringArray : [String]? = nil ` do not need to assign `nil` here and `var completed : Bool!` either assign some value to `completed` of make it optional with `?`

Comment: You haven't initialised your `sharedInstance` with dictionary.

Comment: How to initialized the sharedInstance with dictionary

Comment: We have changed the optional for completed also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use different function to load data and call that after **WebCall**

```
func loadData(Fromarray  dictionary : [String:Any]) {
 completed = dictionary["completed"] as? Bool
 id = dictionary["id"] as? Int
 title = dictionary["title"] as? String
 userId = dictionary["userId"] as? Int
}
```

call after web call completion

```
Singleton.sharedInstance.loadData(FromArray : YourDictoinary)
```

and acess anywhre throught project

```
let title = Singleton.sharedInstance.title
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very poor architectural decision.

Among the many the first problem here is that results of API calls are always asynchronous so you can't tell if your class have been properly initialized at the moment you use it's properties.

You create too much ambiguity by creating forced unwrapped optional that depends on network call. What if API call fails? What if internet connection is slow, how would you predict that your singleton is "fine" at this moment? For most of the cases you will be accessing nil and it will crash your app.

I'd suggest more reading on Singleton pattern (if it's necessary) and also on architectural patterns in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep a single object of your singleton class.

```
static let sharedInstance = Singleton()
```

**It will create a object of your singleton class.**

```
private init() { } or,

init(fromarray dictionary: [String:Any]) {
    completed = dictionary["completed"] as? Bool
    id = dictionary["id"] as? Int
    title = dictionary["title"] as? String
    userId = dictionary["userId"] as? Int
}
```

**It will create another object of your singleton class, which will be differ form above.**

If you need to access the data from your singleton class. Create your class like:

```
class Singleton {

    static let sharedInstance = Singleton()

    var emptyStringArray: [String]?
    var completed: Bool?
    var id: Int?
    var title: String?
    var userId: Int?

    func initializeData(_ dictionary: [String:Any]) {
        completed = dictionary["completed"] as? Bool
        id = dictionary["id"] as? Int
        title = dictionary["title"] as? String
        userId = dictionary["userId"] as? Int
    }
}
```

And use it like:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Initialize with data
    Singleton.sharedInstance.initializeData(["completed": true, "id": 123, "title": "iOS Title", "userId": 572])

    // Access data
    let boolData = Singleton.sharedInstance.completed
    print(boolData)
}
```

Comment: _"You need to keep a single object of your singleton class."_ I believe he just did not share his code properly. That first bit of code seems to be his Singleton class.

Comment: Yes `static let sharedInstance = Singleton()` will create the object for singleton class, but populating data to property via `init()` method will create another object. That's what I am referring to.

Comment: What's the benefits of using init and difference for :
func initializeData(_ dictionary: [String:Any]) and 
init(fromarray dictionary: [String:Any]) ?

Comment: Using `init` will not keep your class as singleton. Adding private accessibility to `init` will prevent it to initialize outside of your class. But if you still populate your data via init then it will be written on different instance than the `Singleton. sharedInstance` and you will not be able to access this data anywhere else outside the scope of newly created init object.